# How to convert mongodb document to binary in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pdf, mongoengine, pdfminer

I'm trying to convert this python command line utility so that I can use the code as a module in my existing program and so that I can feed it a pdf which is stored in MongoDB using [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/).

Currently it takes a filename as a string and gets the file using the following code:

```
fp = file(fname, 'rb')
```

Since I want to put in a document from my mongoDB, I changed the argument of the function to `main(fp)` and did the following from the interactive python interpreter:

```
>>> from app.documents import UserDocument
>>> from app.pdfutils2 import main
>>> doc = UserDocument.objects.first()
>>> main(doc._file.read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "app/pdfutils2.py", line 107, in main
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfpage.py", line 118, in get_pages
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfparser.py", line 43, in __init__
    PSStackParser.__init__(self, fp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer/psparser.py", line 495, in __init__
    PSBaseParser.__init__(self, fp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer/psparser.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.seek(0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer/psparser.py", line 507, in seek
    PSBaseParser.seek(self, pos)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer/psparser.py", line 196, in seek
    self.fp.seek(pos)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Since `fp` is initially created using the `'rb'` flag I suppose I need to create `fp` in binary mode from mongoengine, but I wouldn't know how to convert the GridFS-results from my [FileField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.FileField) into binary mode.

Does anybody have a tip on how I could convert GridFS results into binary so that it is the same as when I retreive it using `file(fname, 'rb')`? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, so for the readers in the future; I should have done

```
main(doc._file)
```

instead of

```
main(doc._file.read())
```

Have a beautiful day!